# Singleton pattern no more working with php 8.1

Tags: php

Here is some simple code that works with php 7.4, but not with php 8.1:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $name = "I'm A";

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        static $instance;
        if (!$instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public $name = "My name is B";
}

echo B::instance()->name . "\n";
echo A::instance()->name . "\n";
```

Now, using this code with php 7.4 will give:

"My name is B"

"I'm A"

While running it with php 8.1 will give:

"My name is B"

"My name is B"

I suspect php developpers had good reasons to make this change, I know the singleton pattern is somewhat deprecated, but I needed to use that code without returning to php 7.4.

Comment: None of the code you've posted runs without error, and trying to correct it just introduces assumptions about what you're trying to do. Please post snippets that are actually runnable and demonstrate the issue at hand.

Comment: @Sammitch: thanks for looking at my code. Yes, you were right, self is not the same as static, and vars in php need a $ prefix. So now running my code works as expected, and produce different results with php7.4 and php8.1.
I hope this demonstrate the issue at hand now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static varibales should always work the same way.
Test this code in 7.4 an 8.1 and you will see the difference in the behavior, and that was fixed by php developers. And the code has also the solution to your issue, using `static::class`.

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $name = "I'm A";

    static $funcCalls = 0;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        static $instance=[];
        static $funcCalls = 0;
        print ++$funcCalls.' - '.(++self::$funcCalls);
        if (!isset($instance[static::class])) {
            print "(new)";
            $instance[static::class] = new static();
        }
        return $instance[static::class];
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public $name = "My name is B";
}

echo B::instance()->name . "\n";
echo A::instance()->name . "\n";
echo A::instance()->name . "\n";
echo B::instance()->name . "\n";
```

PHP 7.4

```
1 - 1 (new)My name is B
1 - 2 (new)I'm A
2 - 3 I'm A
2 - 4 My name is B
```

PHP 8.1

```
1 - 1 (new)My name is B
2 - 2 (new)I'm A
3 - 3 I'm A
4 - 4 My name is B
```

In other words: Why should a class, that extends from another, become its own static variable pointer, when declared in a class method but not when declared as static property?

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static_variable_inheritance

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and the rfc link. Very appreciated!